# Batch command double extension fix

Tags: batch-file, command, double, audio-player

Hi everybody i would like to ask how i can remove a **mistakenly added second file extension** using a batch script.

**E.g. "test.aac.m4a" -> "test.m4a"**

So the **last** extension is the right one which i want to have.
But this is ONLY the case for

```
.aac.m4a
-> .m4a 

and

.m4a.aac
-> .aac
```

I know some batch scripting but

```
ren *.aac.m4a *.m4a
```

**Won't** work :(

Another thing worth mentioning would be that these double extensions come from my music software **MusicBee**.
I use mp4box on m4a files to extract the raw aac stream from the m4a container so i can edit it in other software.
Currently the syntax is:

```
mp4box.exe -raw 1 "<URL>" -out "<URL>".aac

The "<URL>" is the variable MusicBee will replace with the file url.
```

But this will add the .aac extension after the .m4a and i have no idea how to replace it instead. (and again when i repack the files ".aac -> .aac.m4a")

As far as i know MusicBee just replaces the variables and launches the batch code when activated so i think other batch code will work too.

Is it possible to prevent this double extension from even developing?

As always ANY help is apreciated!!

Thanks, Daniel

Comment: Not sure about using batch, but I've used this software when I had a massive rename issue last time: http://www.advancedrenamer.com/ 
If that fits what you need I'll post it as an answer. It doesn't require any command line stuff so it's more of a GUI layman user approach.

Comment: Thank you very much! It works! Even though i don't like to use third party software for this i was able to do this inside MusicBee:
I created two rename batch scripts (those special ones from the advanced renamer software) and put the portable version on my drive to MusicBee. Then i created a shortcut to send the files to AR:
K:\MusicBee\advanced_renamer_portable\arenc.exe -e fix.aac.m4a.aren -f "<URL>"
And it works!!! I hope this will also work on other machines as well =) Thank you very much again!

Comment: It will if you make the path relative and not always to K:\, for example put it into the program files and reference it as %programfiles%/MusicBee/arenc.exe. I've put an answer for you to accept, you're most welcome!

Comment: Thanks, MusicBe will automaticly change the drive letter to where the software is located (own drive) so it should work fine =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In preventing the double extension from developing I'm guessing you're not appending the file extension accordingly in the right way, I am however not familiar at all with Music Bee.

As for creating the right batch files that do what you want, I've used [**Advanced File Renamer**](http://www.advancedrenamer.com/) in the past for all sorts of renaming patterns such as your case. It's **freeware** too! The program has a fairly advanced feature that allows users to write **custom scripts** in JavaScript [user guide here](http://www.advancedrenamer.com/user_guide/method_script). And can even generate batch scripts that do special renaming (as you've noted in the comments) for your specific use case.

For the other less advanced users the program has a GUI that makes it easy to do batch renames.

Best of all, if you're like me that avoids third party software installs just to do one thing as much as possible, the program has a **portable** mode that won't hook itself into your system, which is always good.

Read the manuals and guides there for more information. My answer might sound a little too much like advertising for it, but that's only because it's helped me so much in renaming my music a long time ago.

Here's a screenshot by the OP, RapidFireArts that shows how OP used the software to remove the second file extension.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Thanks again for your solution.
Here is a screenshot which i hope explains how MusicBee handles this: http://prntscr.com/6utg9m

Comment: @RapidFireArts would it be alright for me to attach that in my answer and give you credit for that? nice work! upvoted ur question too.

Answer (score 2):

It ought to be possible, but I have no idea how to work with your software to prevent the double extensions from occurring in the first place. But it is fairly easy to strip off the unwanted middle "extension".

If you know for a fact that none of your .m4a or .aac files are supposed to have multiple dots, then you could simply do the following:

```
ren *.m4a ???????????????????????????????????????????.m4a
ren *.aac ???????????????????????????????????????????.aac
```

Just make sure you have enough `?` wildcards to match the longest name in your folder. See [How does the Windows RENAME command interpret wildcards?](https://superuser.com/q/475874/109090) for an explanation of why this solution works.

But sometimes file names legitimately have additional dots prior to the actual extension. If this is your case, then the following batch script will remove only the unwanted .m4a and .aac middle "extensions"

```
@echo off
for /f "eol=: delims=" %%A in ('dir /b /a-d *.m4a.aac *.aac.m4a') do (
  for %%B in ("%%A") do ren "%%A" "%%~nB%%~xA"
)
```

Another option is to use my [JREN.BAT regular expression file renaming utility](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6081). JREN.BAT is a hybrid JScript/batch script that runs natively on any Windows machine from XP onward. Ideally, the script should be placed within a folder that is included within your PATH. I like to use c:\utils for all of my non-standard utilities.

Once you have JREN.BAT, then all you would need would be

```
call jren "\.(m4a|aac)(?=\.(m4a|aac)$)" ""
```

Provided you understand regular expressions, and you take the time to read the built-in JREN help, then there are many wondrous things you can do with the utility. The help is accessed by issuing `jren /?` from the command line. You might want to use `jren /?|more` if you have not configured your console window to have a large buffer that enables scrolling to see prior output.

Comment: 1. Thank you very much for your comment.
First method will not work for me as some music files may contain more dots (e.g. in artist names) and then length can vary a lot.
Second method would work but i don't know how to handle a batch file with MusicBee correctly, otherwise thats a good solution already.
I don't like to use the third one because it is not possible to place the file where i want to execute it automaticly (it's a bit complicated).
But thank you a lot for your effort.
Currently i have a pretty OK solution which uses [...]

Comment: 2. [...] the portable version of advanced renamer (recommended by  matrixanomaly) and it's command line feature with MusicBee and it seems to do the job.
Here is a screenshot of MusicBee and how it does it's thing. I hope it's understandable =) http://prntscr.com/6utg9m
Regards, Daniel

Answer (score 1):

I use File Renamer Basic.

http://download.cnet.com/File-Renamer-Basic/3000-2248_4-10306538.html

It's Free

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but i would like to use non-third-party tools (e.g. batch) for this (which i didn't really specify, sorry for that!). It's because my music software is set up to work completely portable for plug'n'play so i can't rely on non-portable software for this which doesn't have a command line.